# Getting live content

Tags: javascript, html, live

how can i get the content on enviroment agency website to load up on my site.
i want the current flood warnings so the users of the site can see them

The warnings are at
http://www.environment-agency.gov.uk/homeandleisure/floods/31618.aspx

Nothing i do seems to work, can get them there but not change on page refresh as they chang on the site.
There must be a way but i am a firefighter no wb designer so can any one help

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, It's going to require programming really, so it's not possible for you to do unless you are a programmer I'm afraid.

If you just want to have that 'page' on your site you can include it with an iframe like:

-- Edit:

Update to include auto-refresh.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var MINS = 1;

function my_autoReloadFrame ()
{
    floodFrame.src = "http://www.environment-agency.gov.uk/homeandleisure/floods/31618.aspx";
    setTimeout("my_autoReloadFrame()", MINS * 60 * 1000);
}

function my_setupReload ()
{
    setTimeout("my_autoReloadFrame()", MINS * 60 * 1000);
}
</script>

<iframe onload="my_setupReload();" id="floodFrame" src="http://www.environment-agency.gov.uk/homeandleisure/floods/31618.aspx" width="100%" height="600" border="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not perfect for what i wanted but it works some how got 3 side bars on site now. But the users can at least see the latest flood warnings, Is there a script i can use that i can include in the frames so just that content refreshes.
To me you are a genius

Comment: I've updated it to auto-refresh every 1 minute; change the number 'MINS = 1' to 'MINS = 5' if you want 5 minutes. Note that it will make searching/clicking in that site strange, because the update will cancel whatever the user is doing in that frame.